# tns command cannot be found

Tags: cmd, nativescript

When I type any "tns"-command in cmd. It just tells me, that this command cannot be found.

I´ve been setting up an suiting programming environment for developing a small android app, as a project. I decided to use nativescript with angular, while coding in Microsoft Visual Studio Code und using an emulator from Android Studio. After a long setting up, due to two days working out the correct proxy settings with the help of my colleagues, my playground project first was displayed on the emulator yesterday. I was leaving for home in joy, just to come back today, to find out, i can´t run any tns command now. Thats why I can´t run the project again...

Any ideas how to get it to work again, without reinstalling everything. I don´t want to lose the proxy settings again.

Comment: you can use cmd for example du generate new linked files into a project, or in my case to run the project on an emulator

Comment: okay i got on site support:D

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was editing the PATH variable, to adress the tns.cmd file.
For me it was under: C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: You have hopefully edited __user__ and not __system__ environment variable `PATH` and set the directory with `%APPDATA%\npm` in __user__ `PATH` because of `npm` being installed in your user profile which means for your user account. Other user accounts on same computer do not have read access to `%APPDATA%\npm` of your user account by default with exception of user accounts which belong to local administrators group.